# Оцените реализацию хеш-таблицы

Tags: c++, хеширование

В уездном городе N проводился конкурсный отбор и было дано задание: "реализовать хеш-таблицу". Задание, вроде, несложное, но я не прошёл. Комментариев никаких дано не было, но очень хотелось бы получить обратную связь. Буду рад абсолютно любым комментариям по любому поводу, занудствовать разрешается!

```
// Реализация хеш-таблицы через остаток от деления
// Добавление и поиск элементов осуществлятся через имя (name). В реальных условиях
// такая таблица будет иметь много коллизий, но, поскольку задание является тестовым,
// я избрал самый простой, быстрый и наглядный метод реализации.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define PRIME_SIZE 29 // Использовано просто число

using namespace std;

class Person // Класс, который содержит немного информации о человеке.
{
public:
    Person *next; // При возникновении коллизии элементы будут помещены в односвязный список.
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;

    Person()
    {
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    Person (string name, string surname, int age = 0)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->surname = surname;
        this->age = age;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        //cout << "Delete " << this->name << endl;
        if ( this->next != NULL )
        {
            delete this->next;
        }
    }
};

class HashTable // Хеш-таблица, представленная в виде массива элементов (которые в свою очередь представляют список).
{
    Person *table[PRIME_SIZE];

    // Самая простоя хеш-функция. Считает сумму ASCII кодов, делит на константу и
    // получает остаток от деления.
    static int hash ( string str )
    {
        int asciisum = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
        {
            asciisum += str[i];
        }
        return asciisum % PRIME_SIZE;
    }

public:

    HashTable()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < PRIME_SIZE; i++ )
        {
            table[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~HashTable()
    {
        //cout << "Delete table\n";
        for ( int i = 0; i < PRIME_SIZE; i++ )
        {
            delete table[i];
        }
    }

    // Вставляет элемент в таблицу
    void push ( string name, string surname, int age ) 
    {
        int hashNumber = hash(name);
        Person *pers = new Person(name, surname, age);
        Person *place = table[hashNumber];
        if ( place == NULL )
        {
            table[hashNumber] = pers;
            return;
        }

        while ( place->next != NULL )
        {
            place = place->next;
        }
        place->next = pers;
    }

    // Получает элемент из таблицы по его имени.
    Person* find ( string name )
    {
        int hashNumber = hash ( name );
        Person *result = table[hashNumber];
        if ( !result )
        {
            cout << "Element not found" << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        while ( result->name != name )
        {
            if ( !result->next )
            {
                cout << "Element not found" << endl;
                break;
            }
            result = result->next;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    HashTable newTable;
    newTable.push("Artyom", "Devyatov", 20);
    newTable.push("Vasya", "Petrov", 23);
    newTable.push("Ilja", "Saveljev", 28);
    newTable.push("Ilaj", "Savanna", 43); // Имеет коллизию с Ilja
    newTable.push("Dmitry", "Kuzychev", 31);

    Person * search = newTable.find("Ilaj");
    if ( search )
    {
        cout << search->surname << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Допустим, что задание было сделать хэширование именно объектов `Person`. Причем эти объекты являются неотъемлимой частью таблицы, что следует из рассмотрения метода `push()`. Именно там они создаются из аргументов метода. Более того, деструктор четко показывает на это.  Тогда отставим разговоры об общности программы и наличии ссылки для списка синонимов (`next`) в `Person`.

Сначала все-таки о "мелочах". Константный размер таблицы мне не нравится. Пожалуй, стоило бы предусмотреть конструктор, который позволяет задавать ее размер.

Используемая функция хэширования не выдерживает никакой критики. В простейшем случае для строк используют все же что-то вроде

```
 int hash (char  k[]) {
  int hashsum, i;

  for (hashsum = i = 0; k[i]; i++) 
    hashsum = (hashsum * 31) ^ k[i]; // иногда берут 37
```

которая хоть как-то пытается перемешивать биты ключа.

Нет методов для удаления `Person` (но, тогда и его деструктор, надо менять) и траверса всей таблицы.

Теперь рассмотрим **реальные ошибки.**

**Первая** - метод `hash()` может возращать **отрицательные числа**. Результат очевиден, портим память, индекс массива `table` ошибочный. Можно написать

```
    return (hashsum & 0x7fffffff) % tablesize;
```

**Вторая** - скорее логическая. В методе `push()` не проверяется, что такого ключа (`name` в `Person`) уже нет в списке синонимов.

Если предполагалась реализация "multimap", то тогда`find()` должен возвращать, например, список `Person` с одинаковым ключом. Или надо добавить метод `find_next(Person)`, возвращающий следующий элемент с тем же ключом.

**Третья** - в методе `find()` если заданный ключ не найден в списке синонимов, то возвращается адрес последнего `Person`. Очевидно, в

```
        if ( !result->next )
        {
            cout << "Element not found" << endl;
            break;
        }
```

вместо `break;` надо `return NULL;`

Больше сходу не увидел.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала: у вас `Person` содержит в себе сразу инфраструктуру для хеш-таблицы: поле `next`. Это неправильно:

- зачем расходовать память на `next` для объектов, которые не лежат ни в какой хеш-таблице?
- что, если один объект лежит сразу в нескольких хеш-таблицах?

Затем: у вас размер `table` фиксированный. Это неправильно, при такой реализации поиск будут `О(<к-во элементов в таблице> / PRIME_SIZE)`, то есть линейно расти. Вам нужно динамически расширять таблицу при увеличении количества элементов, чтобы выдержать асимптотику амортизированного O(1).

Затем, если уж пишете на C++, почему не сделать хэш-таблицу темплейтом по типу элемента?

Comment: @VladD, ну рехэширование не слишком дешевая операция. Обычно сводится к построению новой хэш-таблицы.

Comment: @avp: можно хранить вычисленные хэш-значения не по модулю `PRIME_SIZE`, а «как есть», тогда повторно хэшировать не придётся, по идее.

Comment: @VladD, и как по ним поиск (индексацию) делать?

Сбалансированное дерево строить?

Comment: @avp: ну, как обычно. Например (псевдокод)

    bool contains(needle)
    {
        bucketNo = positive_hash(needle) % current_table_size;
        for (entry = buckets[bucketNo]->entry; entry; entry = entry->next)
            if (equals(entry->data, neelde))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

Comment: @VladD, хотите сказать, что при изменении `current_table_size` перемещать элементы не потребуется?

Comment: @avp: элементы — нет, но обёртки (entry) могут разползтись по разным bucket'ам. То есть перестраивать структуру придётся. (Но делать это приходится редко.)

Comment: Так с чего и начали. Либо новая table и переносим за один проход или увеличиваем по месту (`realloc()` (или `vector`) + в `entry` флаг новый/старый) и два прохода. 

Если хотим автоматизировать рехэширование то где-то длину списков коллизий надо хранить или неэффективно вставлять в конец списка (как у ТС  (я чего-то не отметил этот недочет)).

Comment: @avp: создание новой таблицы плохо, т.к. инвалидирует имеющиеся у клиентов указатели на неё. Новая аллокация нужна только для массива `buckets` (который, разумеется, должен быть в куче), плюс пройтись по спискам, «висящим» от каждого старого bucket'а, вычислить новый номер bucket'а и добавить в голову соответвующего нового списка. Повторное вычисление хэша не нужно, вся операция O(n). Поскольку она производится примерно один раз на `alpha * n` вставок, её реальная стоимость амортизированное O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Идея хранения списка объектов `Person` в самом объекте персон очень не удачная. `Person` - это объект для хранения данных о человеке, откуда там взяться ещё и списку других людей? Если нужен список, то можно взять готовый / написать свой и класть туда объекты `Person`.

По самому коду вот набросал замечания
http://pastebin.com/kSWkfumS

Comment: @fogbit, Вы бы лучше все же сюда свои замечания вынесли.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем задание конкретно состояло? По мне так негоже такие велосипеды писать, ведь есть std::map в конце концов. А по коду, в классе Person присвоения лучше в блок инициализации конструктора вынести чтобы пустые конструкторы string не вызывались лишний раз.

Comment: > А в чем задание конкретно состояло? По мне так негоже такие велосипеды писать, ведь есть std::map в конце концов.

@segray, читать умеете? "**реализовать** хеш-таблицу". Что-то мне подсказывает, что использование готовой реализации из STL и собственная реализация - две разные вещи.

Comment: Я просто подумал что им нужна была хеш таблица адаптированная под какие - то конкретные задачи, от того странно было видеть такую реализацию. Если же цель была посмотреть как вы пишите обобщенные алгоритмы, то очевидно что они ожидали, как минимум, что класс Person и hash - функция будут задаваться отдельно через темплейты в HashTable